# Why does Javascript not follow ECMA specs on Infinity/NaN comparisons?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, primitive, comparison-operators, infinity

I have tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari. They all give the same results on these comparisons.

- `0 < NaN` returns `false`.
- `Infinity < Infinity` returns `false`.
- `-Infinity < -Infinity` returns `false`.

While according to the [Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), in the 4h and 4i steps, the above expressions should return `undefined`, `true`, `true`.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Like the note in step `g` asserts, `h`/`i`/`j` are only relevant for comparisons such as `0n < NaN`, `NaN < 0n`, `-Infinity < 0n`, `0n < Infinity`, `Infinity < 0n` and `0n < -Infinity`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lval < rval`, when evaluated, [does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> 5. Let r be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison lval < rval.
> 6. ReturnIfAbrupt(r).
> 7. If r is undefined, return false. Otherwise, return r.

Although "Abstract Relational Comparison"  (ARC) may return `undefined`, the final result of the evaluation of the `<` operator is always `true` or `false`.

The actual comparison of numbers to other numbers is shown in [6.1.6.1.12 Number::lessThan ( x, y )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-lessThan); see how ARC says:

> f. If Type(nx) is the same as Type(ny), return `Type(nx)::lessThan(nx, ny).`

So nothing below step F in ARC is relevant for these expressions you're checking, because in each of the expressions, you're comparing a number to another number.

---

`0 < NaN` fulfills step 2 of `lessThan`:

> If y is NaN, return undefined.

resulting in ARC returning `undefined`, resulting in a final value of `false`: *If r is undefined, return false.*.

`Infinity < Infinity` first fulfills step 6, which is:

> If x is +∞, return false.

`-Infinity < -Infinity` first fulfills step 8, which is:

> If y is -∞, return false.